# Как отражаются в оперативной памяти методы класса?

Tags: java

Как отражаются в оперативной памяти методы класса (ассоциированные, не ассоциированные с объектами класса или безобъектные)? Спасибо!

Comment: @chlamidija у вас уже второй вопрос весьма специфичный. Вы по какому-то интересному учебнику учитесь? Или это в ВУЗе задают?

Comment: Кроме того, как я понимаю "ассоциированных с объектами класса" методов в Java нет - самое близкое это создать анонимный класс, куда и добавить новый метод, но это все равно будет "не ассоциированный с объектом" метод. Или неправильно понимаю?

Comment: Обычно учебники пишут для сформировавшихся специалистов, у которых вопросы возникают редко. "Чайнику" трудно ориентироваться в океане терминов разных по форме, но единых по содержанию. По-этому приходится каждый раз "ломать" себе голову: что же имел автор учебника под своим определением термина.

Comment: Если читаете каких то авторов, то лучше добавлять в вопрос ссылки на их статьи. После этого будет немного понятнее вопрос.

Comment: или я чего-то непонимаю/не знаю или вопрос задан как-то не так... 
 
все методы явно обьявленные в классе или унаследованые в памяти могут быть только в одном месте, - там где лежит загруженный класс (если он загружен конечно). все обьекты этого класса просто ссылаются на этот класс. поэтому если вас интересует сколько раз они будут загружены в память? то ответ 1.

p.s. осветите пожалуйста почему вас заинтересовал этот вопрос, может мы сможем поточнее ответить?

Comment: To @jmu. Совершенно ясно, что автору просто интересно, а как в интерпретаторе (JVM) реализованы такие штуки. Какие структуры данных используются, как они представлены в машинной памяти, какие потоки запущены, таймеры установлены и т.д.

@chlamidia, посмотрите код загрузчика классов, думаю из него можно вытянуть ответ.

Comment: Всем спасибо за внимание к моему вопросу, который я надумал под влиянием источника знаний (на мой взгляд как нельзя лучше подходящего для супер "чайников"):И.Н.Блинов, В.С.Романчик "Практическое руководство по изучению Java" глава 2 подраздел "Ключевое слово static".

Comment: Спасибо всем, за то, что обратили внимание на мой вопрос. Вопрос возник при чтении книги "Практическое руководство по изучению Java" Блинов И.Н., Романчик В.С. раздел 2:Всё есть объекты, подраздел:Ключевое слово static.

Answer (score 5):

В случае Java это никому неизвестно кроме виртуальной машины. :)

Comment: Внутренний голос подсказывает, что Вы правы. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

В оперативной памяти все отображается в виде нулей и единиц. В любом случае, все объекты и команды переводятся в машинный язык. Другое дело, когда надо как-то посмотреть, что виртуальная машина загрузила и в каком количестве, сколько это весит. Это уже другой вопрос. Ну так на него есть простой ответ: есть программы, которые это показывают. Т.е. показывают какие объекты загружены, какие методы в данный момент работают, какая загруженность процессора и оперативной памяти в общем и некоторыми отдельными объектами и т.д.

Comment: Спасибо! Понял, что мне ещё рано заниматься такими вопросами.

Comment: учитывая бритву окама, "в виде нулей и единиц" единственно верный ответ :)

Answer (score 0):

Должно быть как и в С++, стек кода растет снизу вверх - с инструкциями (фреймами вызовов) и всеми переменными, для которых дисплейсмент можно сразу расчитать. Все остальное в куче  и растет сверху вниз.
[stack frame](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80)

З.Ы. Кстати в Java нет инструкций или глобальных констант (без привязки к объектам). Просто интепритатор пихает их копии во все классы, где они используются. Поэтому возможны забавные эффекты, если не пересобирать все модулю проекта целиком )))